# Перевод с C++ на русский или C#

Tags: c#, c++, перекодировка

ДВС!
Помогите расшифровать фрагмент кода:

```
int s = [] (int n) { int i = 1; while(n--) i*=2; return i; }(n);
```

Что все это означает? особенно (n) и (int n) в круглых скобках после того как оно уже было объявлено в программе ранее? Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На C#:

```
int s = ((Func<int, int>)(k => { int i = 1; while (k-- != 0) i *= 2; return i; }))(n);
```

На русский:

- `int s` — объявить переменную `s` типа `int`...
- `=` — ...и инициализировать её значением, равным...
- `[]` — вот тут будет лямбда-функция, это типа функция, но записанная прямо здесь, а не отдельно
- `(int n)` — список аргументов функции — один `int`, назовём его `n`
- `{` — началось тело функции:

  - `int i = 1;` — завели локальную переменную `i`, инициализировали значением 1
  - `while(n--) i*=2;` — пока `n` не равно 0, удвоить `i`; после каждой проверки уменьшить `n`
  - `return i;` — вернуть `i`
- `}` — а это тело функции закончилось
- `(n)` — ...функцию вызываем с аргументом `n`, и результатом вызова инициализируем переменную `s`
- `;` — конец объявления переменной `s`. (Спасибо @GreenDragon за уточнение!)

Comment: С++ принемает лямбды с возвращаемым значением без явной декларации возвращаемого типа?

Comment: @Shadasviar: [да](http://ideone.com/RjgPWk). Да здравствует автовыведение типов!

Comment: А зачем n переименовал? Вроде должно было с орининальным именем прокатить, т. к. функции разные?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не, не хочет. «error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'n' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter»

Comment: Хм.. да... http://ideone.com/H2jwjf А почему я считал, что в функции можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, в плюсах можно же. А в шарпе перекрывать переменные нельзя.

Comment: Разобрался. http://ideone.com/JpsH25 циклофичи - скоуп не тот))) [Simple names are not so simple, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple/) и [Simple names are not so simple, part two](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/05/simple-names-are-not-so-simple-part-two/) :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ого, круто, не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: Новые возможности для запутывания)))

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно! Надо будет где-нибудь применить :)

Comment: Где новое [tag:соревнование]?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Пора бы устроить :)

Comment: В ком-то веки код на C++ выглядит проще чем на C# =) Кстати `;` это не конец инициализации.

Comment: @GreenDragon: Хм, а что это тогда? Конец объявления переменной?

Comment: В данном случае завершение декларации переменной. Подробнее смотрите [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) там где про `simple-declaration`.

Comment: @GreenDragon: Круто, спасибо, обновлю ответ.

Answer (score 3):

это новые штуки с++ - лямбды.

Перепишем на более простой и привычный с++

```
int foo(int n)
{
   int i = 1;
   while (n--) {
     i*=2;
   }
   return i;
}

int s = foo(n);
```

по факту - просто считает 2 в степени n для положительных чисел. Для отрицательных... а там все плохо:)